# How to move text box to the right

Tags: bootstrap-4

I want to move a text box to the right so that I can have a carousel to the left of it. I've tried using float but that doesn't seem to work.

[image]

```
        <div class="col-12 col-md-5">
        </div>
        d-flex align-items-center
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 bg-white d-flex align-items-center border border-dark rounded-right">
            <div class="messageBox">
                <h2>Message From Owner</h2>
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius, dolore. Perferendis aliquam,
                    exercitationem ipsam vel nam cupiditate ratione rem, voluptate tempora accusamus qui quisquam
                    iusto voluptas laudantium excepturi! </p>


                <p>Magni, quisquam. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut in tempora, est
                    corrupti nulla ex, magni vel repudiandae, nisi natus maiores asperiores deserunt explicabo
                    labore! Vero sint eaque aut delectus.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can use the margin property.

Edit: Or you can also use the bootstrap grid.

Edit 2: Here is a link to bootstrap grid documentation

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

and bootstrap grid can be implemented when you want to make something like these

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/
or here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/

and even in your case the bootstrap grid is a great choice as it is highly responsive.

Comment: I'm fairly new to Bootstrap do you have an example of how I could do it.?

Comment: @Stephanie Yeah wait a second I will include the link in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why to play with margin and bootstrap by yourself if flexbox does everything for you and with more ease. All you need is the following code snippet.

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

//Just to visualise the two sections
.textBox, .carousal {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">
  <div class = "carousal">
    Your carousal code goes here...
  </div>
  <div class = "textBox">
    Your message goes here...
  </div>
</div>
```

Play around with `justify-content` for more spacing options. Here's a complete guide if you ran into any issues - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/